# How to view last 5 lines from last created/modified file?

Tags: shell, files, wildcards, timestamps

Every day I have to take backup and update the status to support teams at particular time for which I need to check last 5 lines of last created/modified `*.aff` file in a directory and update them.

Can anyone please let me know how to view last 5 lines from last modified file (particular extension) in linux as with `*.aff` file? other files are also created e.g. `*.log`, etc.

Answer (score 7):

With the `zsh` shell:

```
tail -n 5 ./*.aff(D.om[1])
```

With other shells, it's quite difficult to come up with something reliable if you don't want to make assumptions on what file names may contain.

For instance, the `bash` equivalent, if you're on a recent GNU system would be:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.aff' -type f -printf '%T@:%p\0' |
  sort -rzn |
  sed -zn 's/[^:]*://p;q' |
  xargs -r0 tail -n 5
```

Or:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.aff' -type f -printf '%T@/%p\0' |
  sort -rzn | (IFS=/ read -rd '' mtime file && tail -n 5 "$file")
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming file names don't contain newline characters and that all the `*.aff` files are regular files:

```
ls -t1d -- *.aff | head -n 1
```

gives you the name of the most recently modified `.aff`-file. If you want the last 5 lines just do:

```
tail -n 5 -- "$(ls -t1d -- *.aff | head -n 1)"
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for useful comments. Hope OP have not use file names started with `-`or `.`. Regarding `-r` I have miss that it isn't `ls -l` command which prints `total` in fist line.

Answer (score 0):

Another safe approach that should work on any GNU system and Busybox:

```
tail -n5 "$(stat -c "%Y %n" ./* | 
    sort -nk1,1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2- | tail -n1)"
```

That will work on most things but if your file names can contain newlines, use this instead (GNU only, still breaks if your files end in newlines):

```
tail -n5 "$(stat --printf "%Y %n\0" ./* | 
    sort -rznk1,1 | sed -zn 's/[0-9]\+ //p;q')"
```

Comment: %X is last access time. That assumes a recent GNU system, that file names don't start with `-` or `.`. That they are all regular files. The second also assumes filename don't end in newline characters.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, I think I fixed everything but the final newline. `sort -z` is GNU also isn't it?

Comment: yes, supported since 1996. FreeBSD used to use GNU sort, it's now got a clone which also supports `-z`. It's GNU `sed`'s `-z` that is recent (2012).

Comment: @Costas OK, I prefer `--printf` because I want the `\t` but that seems to only work for GNU `stat`. Busybox `stat` [also accepts](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) `-c` though so you're right, that's more portable, thanks. It still [fails on OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) (and presumably BSD) because their `stat` don't have `--format` or `--printf` (they need `-f` instead) but I can live with that.